# Using IF statements in SQL

Tags: sql, sybase

I'm trying to write a sql script to run against a sybase database.  Basically I need a script that queries a version of software, then I need an IF statement that says if the version is so and so run the below script, else run a different script.  The issue that i'm having is that when testing this script, I'm running against a DB that is not the version I set to search for, yet it is still jumping into the body of that IF statement.  Please see code below:

```
DECLARE @exdate datetime, @doc_num varchar (30), @row_count int, @tracknum varchar (6), @pd_version varchar (20), @gng int
SELECT  @pd_version = cnstnt_val from sys_constant_ref where cnstnt_id = 6
SELECT  @exdate = getdate()
SELECT  @doc_num = 'Test'
SELECT  @tracknum = 'Test'
INSERT  INTO dbo.crt_script(script_id, script_name, user_id, date_tmsp, ticket_nmbr, utility_fl, doc_nmbr)
VALUES  (@tracknum, "SCRIPT NAME", suser_name(), @exdate,"SR_NBR", 0, @doc_num)
SELECT @pd_version
If (@pd_version = '4.2 Incr 2 SR17')
    BEGIN
    SELECT @row_count = COUNT(*) FROM dbo.snapshot_mstr  WHERE dbo.snapshot_mstr.obj_usr_num = @doc_num
                    IF (@row_count > 0) 
                                    BEGIN               
                                        SELECT 'Snapshot data found. No changes made to the database. Please open document in PD² and either accept or decline restoration of snapshot data then save and close the document prior to re-execution of this script.'
                                    END
                    ELSE
                                    BEGIN
                                     Select 'No Snapchat data2'   /*MANIP SCRIPT HERE*/
                                    END
    END
ELSE
    If (@pd_version <> '4.2 Incr 2 SR17')
        BEGIN
            Select 'No Snapchat data'  /*MANIP SCRIPT HERE*/
        END
```

Comment: Which version of DB you have and to which IF you are referring?

Comment: I'm in 4.2 Incr 2 SR15  but it proceeds to run SR17 if statement which causes a problem because the table in SR17 doesn't exist in SR15 only in SR17

Comment: did you try to debug, e.g. display or save value of @pd_version before the IF statement?

Comment: Yeah, i confirmed that it is pulling the version, and I ran just the if statement with the non SR17 and it works, but when i add the SR17 if statement back in it still runs that body, even if I put that IF statement after the if statement for non SR17

Comment: Can you try CASE WHEN http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00801.1510/html/iqrefso/X315691.htm

Comment: Tried that and got the same results

Comment: it would help if you add trace that you get to your question

Comment: Not sure how to do that...I'll look into it